# How to make thread work in order and run many times?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 thread which i would like it to print in order but when I run the program it's keep getting result . I don't understand how it couldn't run thread in order. I would like to continue run thread 1 and 2 and 3 respectively. In each thread there is a loop for printing it's multiple times. So I would like to  make the main thread to run each thread in order. This is my code.

```
 threadMessage("Starting MessageLoop thread");
 long patience = 
 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
 Thread t2 = new Thread(new MessageLoop2());
 Thread t3 = new Thread(new MessageLoop3());
 t.setPriority(10);
 t2.setPriority(5);  
 t3.setPriority(1);
 t.start();
 t2.start();
 t3.start();
```

---

This is my thread function(3 threads)

```
private static class MessageLoop
    implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

        try {
            for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
            {      
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 // Print a message
                 threadMessage("A");
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            threadMessage("thread interrupted");
        }
    }
}
private static class MessageLoop2
implements Runnable {
public void run() {

    try {
        for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
        {      Thread.sleep(1000);
             // Print a message
             threadMessage("B");
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        threadMessage("thread interrupted");
    }
}
 private static class MessageLoop3
implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    String importantInfo = "E";
    try {
       for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
       {      
           Thread.sleep(1000);
            // Print a message
            threadMessage(importantInfo);
       }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        threadMessage("Thread interrupted");
    }
}
```

---

And this is my code to make it run in order. I want to make my program run in order like this MessageLoop1 and 2 and 3 respectively.

```
        while (t.isAlive()) {
        threadMessage("Still waiting...");

        t.join(2000);
        if (((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) > patience)
                && t.isAlive()) {
              threadMessage("Tired of waiting!");
              t.interrupt();
                              // Shouldn't be long now
              // -- wait indefinitely
              t.join();

          }
        while(t2.isAlive()){
            threadMessage("Still waiting...");
            t2.join(1000);
            if (((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) > patience)
                    && t2.isAlive()) {
                  threadMessage("Tired of waiting!");
                  t2.interrupt();
                                  // Shouldn't be long now
                  // -- wait indefinitely
                  t2.join();

              }
        }
            while(t3.isAlive()){
                threadMessage("Still waiting...");
                t3.join(1000);
                if (((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) > patience)
                       && t3.isAlive()) {
                      threadMessage("Tired of waiting!");
                      t3.interrupt();
                                      // Shouldn't be long now
                      // -- wait indefinitely
                      t3.join();

                  }

            }
        }
```

---

But the result is coming like B,A,C. Can anyone explain this situation? And are my code wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You don't control the order; the operating system does.  If order matters, then they should not be in separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

That's how threads work. You don't get a guarantee at all which thread will finish first - and that's by design.

I assume what you want, is actually what the jdk calls a future and an ExecutorService.

(pseudocode - will have syntax errors)

```
ExecutorService s = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
try {
Future f1 = s.submit(new MessageLoop()); 
Future f2 = s.submit(new MessageLoop2()); 
Future f3 = s.submit(new MessageLoop3()); 
f1.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  // waits for the first thread to finish
// first thread finished now
f2.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
// second thread finished now
// ...

} finally  { s.shutdown(); }
```

very important is to manage the proper shutdown of the ExecutorService, as the executor service will manage a couple of threads that run until you terminate them. if you don't shut it down, then your applicationo will not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you assume you are controlling order?

The individual MessageLoop implementations are not blocked from executing in any way. So they just will run at the descretion of the thread scheduling.

You would need to introduce a shared ressource that takes the role of lock between the control thread (trying to enforce the order) and the worker threads.

In your current code the control thread just applies a special sequence on collecting the termination of the workers. That may have been executed and completed earlier in time.

If you are interested in a sequential execution and do not want to execute the tasks inline (same thread as your control), then you might just execute the threads in sequence to achieve your goal of sequential execution. (start each thread and wait for termination before starting another).

As you seam to have a restriction on the order of execution you would need some semaphore to coordinate such execution.

Comment: if you started the threads in sequence, you would still have the same issue ;)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant to express, start t1 wait for termination, start t2... and so on.